# Notepad++ > Emmet: "Go to matching pair" won't work?

Tags: notepad++, emmet

I’m having an issue with the Emmet’s `Go to matching pair` feature in Npp, which is not working (unlike, for example, “Match pair inward/outward”).

#### Does anyone have the same problem or a solution for this?

- I know I can use HTML Tag plugin for that.
- I'm using the latest version of the editor and the plugin.

Thank you!

Comment: are you using zencoding?

Comment: @kamol chandra Roy No, I'm not. I believe it's the previous name of this project, isn't it?